# Azure functions java project visual studio code error for dependencies

Tags: java, azure, maven, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am trying to use VSCode to create azure function and deploy it to azure. I followed the official documentation as described,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-vs-code?pivots=programming-language-java.

I am able to run project but getting errors for dependencies mentioned in pom.xml file.

missing artifact org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar1.3

failed to read artifact descriptor for com.mircosoft.azure:azure-functions-java-core:jar1.0.0.-beta-1

missing artifact com.microsoft.aure:azure-functions-java-core:jar1.0.0-beta-1

missing artifact junit:junit:4.12

### complete error trace:

```
{
```

failed to read artifact descriptor for com.mircosoft.azure:azure-functions-java-core:jar1.0.0.-beta-1
"resource": "/c:/Users/name/vsProject/pom.xml",
"owner": "*generated_diagnostic_collection_name*#3",
"code": "0",
"severity": 8,
"message": "Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-java-core:jar:1.0.0-beta-1\n\norg.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-java-core:jar:1.0.0-beta-1\r\n\tat org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)\r\n\tat org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:541)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:524)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:412)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:352)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:284)\r\n\tat org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)\r\n\tat org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:200)\r\n\tat org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:124)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:630)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:65)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:550)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.lambda$3(ProjectRegistryManager.java:514)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:512)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:364)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:315)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:409)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.lambda$1(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:358)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:101)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1370)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:357)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:343)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.managers.MavenBuildSupport.update(MavenBuildSupport.java:87)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.managers.ProjectsManager$3.runInWorkspace(ProjectsManager.java:355)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:42)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)\r\nCaused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-java-core:pom:1.0.0-beta-1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-java-core:pom:1.0.0-beta-1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out\r\n\tat org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:424)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)\r\n\tat org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)\r\n\t... 33 more\r\nCaused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-java-core:pom:1.0.0-beta-1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-java-core:pom:1.0.0-beta-1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out\r\n\tat org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:225)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:193)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:559)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:483)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:401)\r\n\t... 36 more\r\n",
"source": "Java",
"startLineNumber": 1,
"startColumn": 1,
"endLineNumber": 1,
"endColumn": 1
missing artifact org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar1.3
missing artifact com.microsoft.aure:azure-functions-java-core:jar1.0.0-beta-1
missing artifact junit:junit:4.12
}

### pom.xml snippet:

```
'<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-functions-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta-3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
      </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>'
```

**Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your network connection works well and Open Command Palette, clean java language server workspace.

You can turn to [Maven Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer) and find the missed dependencies then add them to `pom.xml`,

**OR**

Open Command Palette and choose **Maven: Add a dependency...**, then select missed dependencies the error mentioned.
Then **rebuild** the project. Try and see if it solves your question.

**[UPDATE]**

The error said

> Failure to transfer
> com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-java-core:pom:1.0.0-beta-1 from
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
> repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
> interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.

The easiest way to resolve this is to delete the dependencies or artifacts which maven has appended with the `.lastUpdated` prefix.  Only after that can you successfully Update Dependencies of your maven project.

Please try this solution: [Maven error “Failure to transfer…”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer)

Comment: Dependencies are already available in pom.xml. I have added pom.xml in the original post.

Comment: @Ashwinee. I've update my answer, please have a try.

Comment: Dependencies errors are gone with first run after above step u mentioned.. But it appeared again for second and next run. Also while running when I tried to call the function with url : [http://localhost:7071/api/hello?name=azure] shows no output.
Example I am trying to execute is from [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-vs-code?pivots=programming-language-java.]
**Have you tried executing this example?**

Comment: @Ashwinee. I don't have azure account, so I didn't try it, but maven template projects could be run successfully on my machine. Did you set jdk which version is lower than jdk11 as `java.home`?

Comment: @Molly.Ok. I am using JDK 8

Comment: @Ashwinee. Java extension needs jdk11 or recent version to support. Install the required jdk and set it as `java.home`, the error should go away.

Comment: yes I tried with jdk 11 but I was facing issue mentioned here : 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61149061/azure-functions-project-using-visual-studio-code-in-java] and so I switch the `java.home` to jdk 8

Comment: @Ashwinee. that's weird. i'll keep researching and you may ask in [vscode-java](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/new) for more help.

Comment: sure. Thanks @Molly

Comment: @Ashwinee, jdk11 is fine, I test with other's account and get the name response. Did you see the tutorial [run the function locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/vscode-function-app-http-trigger/tutorial-vscode-serverless-node-test-local) and can you share your github issue link?

Comment: @Ashwinee, Keep `java.home` still as jdk11, you can specify your project using jdk8, In pom.xml of a Maven project:
`<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>`

Comment: I already have `<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <functionAppName>myFunction-12345</functionAppName>
    </properties>` set in `pom.xml` and now java.home to jdk11
but still when I hit the url `http://localhost:7071/api/hello?name=Azure` it doesn't show me any response. Not sure what I am missing :(

Comment: Github issue link - `https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1985`

Can you share function.java file ?

Comment: @Ashwinee. Sure. Here it is: [Function.java](https://github.com/molly-w/vsc-Java/blob/main/Function.java)